# Printing vector out in functions

Tags: c++, vector

I need to print the vector i have filled in listInput. When i go to listPrint the program crashes. What can i do to fix it? Here is my main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "func.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    subjects a;
    int r=1;
    while(r!=0){
        int select=a.userChoice();
        switch(select){
            case 1:
            a.listPrint();
            break;

            case 2:
            listInput(a);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My header:

```
#ifndef SUBJECT
#define SUBJECT

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class subjects{
    private:
        std::string subjectName;
        std::string lectName;
        std::string lectSurname;
        int credits;
        int studentnum;

    public:
    /*  subjects(){
            subjectName="";
            lectName="";
            lectSurname="";
            credits=0;
            studentnum=0;
        }*/
        int userChoice();
        int enterNumber(std::string name);
        void menu();
        std::string getSubjectName(){
            return subjectName;
        }
        std::string getLectName(){
            return lectName;
        }
        std::string getLectSurname(){
            return lectSurname;
        }
        int getCredits(){
            return credits;
        }
        int getStudentNum(){
            return studentnum;
        }
        friend void listInput(subjects a);
        void listPrint();
        bool checkName(std::string &text);
        std::vector<subjects*> entry;
        subjects(const std::string subjectName="", const std::string lectName = "", const std::string lectSurname="", const int credits = 0, const int studentnum = 0) : 
            subjectName(subjectName),
            lectName(lectName),   
            lectSurname(lectSurname),   
            credits(credits),   
            studentnum(studentnum){
}

};

#endif
```

And my function file:

```
    void listInput(subjects a){
        .
        .
        .
        a.entry.push_back(new subjects(a.subjectName, a.lectName,a.lectSurname,a.credits, a.studentnum));
        }

    void subjects::listPrint(){
        for(int i=0; i<entry.size(); i++){
            cout<<entry[i]->getSubjectName()<<" "<<entry[i]->getLectName()<<" "<<entry[i]->getLectSurname()<<" "<<entry[i]->getCredits()<<" "<<entry[i]->getStudentNum()<<endl;
        }

    }
```

I know that using friend functions arent recommended, but i am required to use atleast one of them. Also if i print the vector in listInput, then it only prints the first entry. If there is more than one entry in the vector, it also crashes.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? I have a feeling most of this code is unnecessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show your work. What did you find when you used a debugger to step through your code? (Don't answer me; edit your question and indicate your debugging results.) If you haven't done that yet, then you're asking the people in this forum to debug your code for you, which no one wants to do.

Comment: Done @Kevin, minimized it

Comment: Don't know why it crashes, but `listInput` takes its parameter by value, so all the updates are made to *a local copy* of the vector.

Comment: Thanks, a really stupid mistake, you saved me a lot of nerves @BoPersson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the a instance by value to the list function and then you try to print it. You should consider passing it by reference if you plan to use it outside the scope of the list function.